# MongoDB 64 on Raspberry Pi 3 with SLES 12 64 bit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4

I am trying to run MongoDB 3.4 on raspberry pi 3 with an OS which was made by SUSE and SUSE is the only official 64 bit OS for raspberry pi (SLES 12 SP2). I have downloaded the MongoDB from the link below:

https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=server:database&package=mongodb

It is the only version which I became able to install properly but when the installation finishes, the service mongodb doesn't start with the error saying that: "Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating". In the config file and by command I tried to change the storage engine to mmapv1 but it's unknown by mongodb according to the error log. Can anybody help me how to solve this problem and run mongodb 64 on raspberry pi 3?

Comment: Worth checking the spec of the build as per this thread: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/524031-Unknown-engine-problem-in-MongoDB-aarch64-on-raspberry-pi-3  Implies that its broken and needs a fix to specify arm64